# set of solutions of inhomogenous linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve the following exercise:

Given is a linear map $F: V \rightarrow W$. I want to show that if F(x) = b has some solution $x_0$, then the set of solutions of the inhomogeneous equation is given by $x_0 + Ker F$.

This is my idea how to solve - I would appreciate feedback:

(1) Given $x_1$ belongs to Ker F, then $F(x_1) = 0$.
Then $F(x_0 + x_1) = F(x_0) + F(x_1) = b + 0 = b$, hence $x_0 + x_1$ is indeed a solution to the inhomogeneous equation

(2) Also, I want to show that this holds for any particular solution $x_2$, i.e. if F($x_2$) = b, then also $x_2 + x_1$ is a solution ($x_1$ again belonging to the kernel of the linear map F) - is this direction of thought correct? And if so, how would I show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote by $S$ the set of solutions of the inhomogeneous equation $F(x) = b$, then your argument (1) shows $x_0 + Ker F \subseteq S$.
Next, you have to show $S \subseteq x_0 + Ker F$.
Here's a hint. Pick any $x_1 \in S$ and show $x_1 - x_0 \in Ker F$. Why is this useful?

Comment: I see. So I dont need to show what I have called (2) in my suggestion, since $x_0$ was chosen to be arbitrary anyway. $x_1$ in your case is another solution to the inhomogeneous equation, right? well then  I guess that here $x_1$ can be written as $x_0$ plus some element of the kernel?

Comment: Yes, your suggested step (2) is not really necessary. And yes, my $x_1$ is another solution of the inhomogeneous equation. I said $x_1 \in S$. One of the fun things about math is that you can express a lot of information with very few symbols. :-) And yes, with your final guess, you're on the right track.

Comment: on the right track - so its not done yet..? :-)

Comment: Well, it's not enough to have the general idea. You also have to write out the details.